# Count Number of users registered today and yesterday PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to echo number of users registered on my site's admin panel today[counting] and yesterday using PHP.

I am saving their signup date in this format

> 2017-01-09 20:32:40

After googling i found this

```
$daterange = "24 HOUR"; 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*)  
FROM ad_total_today      
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL $daterange) 
<= FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time)"; 

$res = mysql_query($sql); 
$today = mysql_result ($res, 0, 0);
```

But I cant seem to understand it.Can anyone help me echo Total number of users registered today and yesterday?

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: *"But I cant seem to understand it"* - can't understand what exactly? where are you echoing it and are there any errors? The question IMHO is both too broad and unclear; mostly unclear though. The schema is unknown as to where UNIXTIME is/what.

Comment: This is just the sql query .When i try to echo $today . i get errors.
i want to echo total number of users registered on my site yesterday
and echo them in admin panel

Comment: ...errors, again, being "what"?

Comment: ok, someone popped an answer below, ask them. Maybe it's the "magic" answer you were looking for.

Comment: If you are going to use SQL, study enough so you can understand the code that you have found.  It is not difficult; however, don't use the deprecated  "mysql_" functions.

Comment: Just like @GordonLinoff said. To put this in another way: *"If you don't know about the race car you're driving or don't know how to drive (a car) yet, don't get in the driver's seat until you know exactly what you're dealing with, and the parts required to fix it, when it does break"*.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use the MySQL function `CURDATE()`, format your column to date-only with `DATE()` (so we don't have to deal with hour/seconds/minutes). Then you select what's equal to today or yesterday. I've used the `SUBCAT()` function to subtract one day from `CURDATE()`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`
FROM ad_total_today 
WHERE DATE(date_time) = CURDATE() 
   OR DATE(date_time) = SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1)
```

Alternatively, you can use `IN` instead of two conditions.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`
FROM ad_total_today 
WHERE DATE(date_time) IN (CURDATE(), SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1))
```

---

You should **really** stop using MySQL functions, they are old, deprecated, insecure and no longer maintained. Switch to either PDO or MySQLi - and don't forget to use parameterized queries with placeholders when dealing with variables in your query - this is the only way to protect your data from SQL injection.

## References and readingmaterial

- [MySQL Date and Time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)
- [Choose an MySQL API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)
- http://php.net/pdo and http://php.net/mysqli
- [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  
FROM ad_total_today      
WHERE DATE_SUB IN (CURDATE(), CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```